# How to delete all rows in sql except one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DELETE FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center]
WHERE [Contact Center] IS NULL
  AND [F2] IS NULL
```

How can I modify the query so after execution ONLY row 15 is still showing and every other row is deleted?

Comment: Do you have a unique primary key for that row?

Comment: Unfortunately no...I had to use three OR statements and it worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some other way to delete except the specific row:

```
DELETE FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center] WHERE F10 NOT IN (2096)
```

You can also `Select` the particular record into a temporary table, then drop the original table and finally copy the data from the temporary table to the original table. Something like this:

```
create table #ContactCenter as
select * from [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center] where F10 = 2096

truncate table [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center]

insert into [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center]
    select * from #ContactCenter
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now you could simply do this, **assuming this record is the only one having a F10 value of 2096**:

```
DELETE FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center] 
WHERE F10 <> 2096
```

However, in the long run you are bound to have other problems with such a design. This table needs a [primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011.aspx) and proper field definitions. Urgently.

Answer (score 1):

you mean you want to delete all the row except **115**?

if so then use the below one --

```
DELETE FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[Contact Center] 
WHERE ([Contact Center] IS NOT NULL OR [F2] IS NULL)
```

Comment: well @JoeW check it again.. I said where **contact_center** IS NOT NULL.. and you think I said IS NULL

Comment: @JoeW good you found your mistake.. :) no prob it happens.. :)